# Unity Shader Compilation strips keyword STEREO_MULTIVIEW_ON on GLES3

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl-es, shader, unity-xr

I am developing my own Unity XR plugin but I'm having trouble getting the Multiview (Singlepass) feature to work.

After inspecting the shaders by **compiling and showing the code**, I discovered that Unity is not using the `STEREO_MULTIVIEW_ON` keyword to compile them. However, the Oculus XR Plugin does use this keyword to compile my shaders.

I'm confused as to why `STEREO_MULTIVIEW_ON` is being stripped in my implementation.